# IO Expander runs very hot

Tags: gpio, webiopi

I have a weird problem and I hope someone here can help me.

I wrote a little script using WebIOPi to control the IO expander which is called IO Pi 32 Channel Port Expander ([schematic](http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/docs/stock/raspberrypi/iopi/IOPi-schematic.pdf) and [overview](http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/18/IO-Pi-32-Channel-Port-Expander-for-the-Raspberry-Pi)), a MCP23017 device.

When I tested my code today one side of the expander started running very hot, and I can't stop it from doing so. I stopped webiopi completely but as soon as the pi boots, it starts heating up.

Anybody has an idea what causes this?

Comment: What do you have connected to the IO expander?

Comment: Nothing, I just tested yet.

Comment: When you say 'very hot', what are you talking about? is it just hot to the touch, or have you got some reading on the actual temp? The device is rated for -40 to +125 Degrees C. What voltage are you running it at? The device can handle between 1.8v and 5.5v. (source : http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=MCP23017)

Comment: Can you post a schematic of how you have the MCP23017 wired to the Pi?